# Python HTTP server endless loop on POST response while returing multiprocessing queue

Tags: python, http, post, server, multiprocessing

Heyo

I have basic `HTTPServer` and `pcsc_listener` process that waits for user card scan. Both are run in using `multiprocessing`.

I have difficulty passing scanned card id from first `pcsc_listener` to `HTTPServer` as POST response - it just endlessly loops on first request, won't close and on 2nd request it just breaks.

My main function:

```py
# Main routine
def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        queue = manager.Queue()
        p1 = Process(target=pcsc_listener, args=(queue,)).start()
        p2 = Process(target=http_server, args=(queue,)).start()
        
        while True:
            msg = queue.get()
            
            if msg:
                if msg[0] == "active_card":
                    print("Card scanned " + msg[1])
```

Since card scanning `pcsc_listener` simply adds list to queue via `queue.put([...])`, it is safe to assume it works, so I won't add its code here.

My http server:

```py
def http_server(queue):
    def error_handler(request, client_address):
        raise

    class http_handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
            '''
            We are totally ignoring GET requests, but we going to leave it open for them.
            Let's just return 501
            '''
            self.error_content_type('application/json')
            self.send_error(501)
            self.end_headers()

        def do_POST(self):
            content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
            post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length).decode("utf-8") \
                if content_length > 0 else ""
            post_data = json.loads(post_data)
            pass_data = {}

            while True:
                msg = queue.get()
                if msg[0] == "active_card":
                    print(msg[1])
                    break

            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
            self.end_headers()


            self.wfile.write(json.dumps(post_data).encode("utf-8"))
            raise(RuntimeWarning(post_data))


        def log_message(self, format, *args):
            return
```

**Why is it not returning Queue and endlesly loops HTTP POST and doesn't return response?**

What am I doing wrong. I basically need to share variable between these processes, so I'm okay with other suggestions.

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For instance, where is the definition of function `pcsc_listener`? I need to be able to copy and paste your code in an attempt to duplicate your problem. I don't want to guess what this missing, correct function is doing. Please assemble *all* of your code together and tag your question with your platform (e.g. `windows`, `linux`, etc.), removing  tag `post` in order to do that.

Comment: Here is the full code (slightly edited but same issue). https://www.mycompiler.io/view/B051f0F But I think I found issue - I'm hanging on loop without it breaking it. Also platform doesn't really matter in this scenario. I'm coding on Windows but testing for Linux (on VM). You won't be able to test my code without PCSC reader, so that's why I tried to be as simple as possible in regards of explaining the situation. Issue is with getting queued list in running processes both inside and outside of both of them.

Comment: Why are both `http_handler.do_POST` and your main function both executing `msg = queue.get()`? Isn't there a possible conflict there?

Comment: Might be that I forgot commenting out bottom one. Since I'm fairly new to multiprocessing, I'm trying to access last queued list from http process. Actually there might be yeah. I'll get back later.. i'm testing another approach.